# How can I find the intersection of two arrays using Hash functions in C++?

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I am new to hash and not sure how to do this in C++. In java, we have functions like ContainsKey, put, get etc for Hash. Is there anything similar in C++?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with `std::set<>`, which is a balanced binary tree.  Most recent compilers also provide `unordered_set<>`, which is a hash table but not part of C++03: it will be part of C++0x.  The boost library also has a hash set implementation.

For std::set<>, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/

e.g.

```
std::set<int> s;
for (int i = 0; i < first_vector.size(); ++i)
    s.insert(first_vector[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < second_vector.size(); ++i)
    if (s.find(second_vector[i]) != s.end())
        do_something();
```

Comment: Intersection is an operation on sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: @Ben: yes - realised that when I went to provide a sample implementation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably wanting the `unordered_set` class.  It's part of TR1 and standardized in C++0x, older compilers can find an implementation in the boost library.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::map`, you can do similar things as `HashMap` in java

Comment: `std::map` is not a hash table.  Also, intersection is an operation on sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: @Ben I agree on std::map is not a hashtable. but intersection can still be performed on dictionaries, since key in dictionaries is uniquely identified. correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can do an intersection on the set of dictionary keys and just ignore the values.... but why pay extra to store values you aren't going to use?